# undefined method `graft' for class `ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4 and getting this error, when try to launch rails console

```
undefined method `graft' for class `ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of squeel gem.
Adding this line:

```
gem "polyamorous", :github => "activerecord-hackery/polyamorous"
```

should help.

Comment: I have not used `squeel` gem. Still, I am trying to add a `polyamorous` gem. But no luck. Facing error for `rake db:setup'` rake aborted!
NameError: undefined method 'graft' for class `ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency'

Answer (score 3):

Squeel gem doesn't work with Rails 4. It's discussed [here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel/issues).